# Missing field 'SetIdentifier' in Change when deleting/upserting with ChangeResourceRecordSets Boto3

Tags: python-2.7, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I've struggled for a week trying to delete/upsert a simple Route 53 resource record with Boto3 v1.10.39.

#### My code:

```
resp=r53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
    HostedZoneId=<ZONE_ID>,
    ChangeBatch={
        'Comment': 'del_ip',
        'Changes': [
            {
                'Action': 'DELETE',
                'ResourceRecordSet': {
                    'Name': <SUBDOMAIN>,
                    'Type': 'A',
                    'Region': 'us-east-1',
                    'TTL': 300,
                    'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': <OLD_IP>}]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

#### Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 272, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 576, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInput: An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: Invalid request: Missing field 'SetIdentifier' in Change with [Action=DELETE, Name=<SUBDOMAIN>., Type=A, SetIdentifier=null]
```

#### Troubleshoot steps:

1. I've gone through all possible documentations (Boto3, AWSCLI, AWS developer guide), the 'SetIdentifier' field is only required when it's not a simple RR (weighted, multivalue, failover etc.):

   - **[SetIdentifier](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html)** (string)

     Resource record sets that have a routing policy **other than simple**: An identifier that differentiates among multiple resource record sets that have the same combination of name and type, such as multiple weighted resource record sets named acme.example.com that have a type of A. In a group of resource record sets that have the same name and type, the value of SetIdentifier must be unique for each resource record set.

     For information about routing policies, see [Choosing a Routing Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html) in the Amazon Route 53 Developer Guide.
2. Tried the same operation with AWS CLI, same error as calling with Boto3.
3. Called **list_resource_record_sets** and verified there's no set identifier value exists.
4. Tried to add 'SetIdentifier': None, 'SetIdentifier': '' and 'SetIdentifier': , none of them works, which make sense as the original RR doesn't have this property at all.

#### Environment:

- OS: amzn-ami-hvm-2015.09.1.x86_64-gp2
- Python: v2.7.14
- BOTO3: v1.10.39
- botocore: 1.13.39
- aws-cli: v1.16.301

I'm wondering if this is a bug from AWS API.

Answer (score 5):

Created an issue in Boto3 github and got help from them saying removing 'Region' attribute is going to fix my issue, and it works like a charm for my code once I do that.

```
resp=r53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
HostedZoneId=<ZONE_ID>,
ChangeBatch={
    'Comment': 'del_ip',
    'Changes': [
        {
            'Action': 'DELETE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': <SUBDOMAIN>,
                'Type': 'A',
                'TTL': 300,
                'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': <OLD_IP>}]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

)